# How to extract 7z files content in String

Tags: java, 7zip

I am trying to extract a 7z file which contains multiple XML entries. I am able to do this for zip format but for 7z its giving me error. For zip format I am using Enumeration to get the entries which works but it does not work for 7z

I can not add main code as it has some internal libraries but I made this in a general code and below is the error I receive

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.buildDecodingStream(SevenZFile.java:1175)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.getInputStream(SevenZFile.java:1351)
    at com.unzip.SevenZStringExtract.unzipFiles(SevenZStringExtract.java:89)
    at com.unzip.SevenZStringExtract.main(SevenZStringExtract.java:53)
```

Error is on line:

```
          String extractedXML = getXML( stream.getInputStream( entry ) ).toString();
```

Below is the code I am using:

```
package com.unzip;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

/**
 * @author vaisahl
 */
public class SevenZStringExtract
{
  
  private static final String CHAR_SET_UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
  private static final String TYPE_XML       = "xml";
  private static final String YES            = "yes";

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    File file = new File( "C://Users//Zip//ABC.7z" );
    

    unzipFiles( file );
  }

  private static File unzipFiles( File file )
  {
    
    String modifiedXML = null;        
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    File outputXMLFile = new File( "C://Users//Zip//Extract7z.xml" );
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = null;
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    Document doc = null;
    SevenZFile stream = new SevenZFile( file );
    SevenZArchiveEntry entry;

    try
    {
      out.append( "<Items>" );
      while ( ( entry = stream.getNextEntry() ) != null )
      {
        System.out.println( entry.getName() );

        if ( !entry.isDirectory() )
        {
          System.out.println( "Entered in if loop of while" );

          String extractedXML = getXML( stream.getInputStream( entry ) ).toString();
          
          //some xml proessing
          if ( extractedXML.contains( "xx " ) ) //$NON-NLS-1$
          {
            //then append kind of things          

        }
      }
      }
      out.append( "</Items>" );
      modifiedXML = out.toString();
      doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                  .newDocumentBuilder()
                                  .parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( modifiedXML ) ) );
      
      //outputXMLFile = new File( destDir, "Merged.xml" );
      TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

      if ( transformerFactory != null )
      {

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        if ( transformer != null )
        {
          transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.ENCODING, CHAR_SET_UTF_8 );
          transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, TYPE_XML );
          transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, YES );
          transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, YES );

          Source xmlSource = new DOMSource( doc );
          Result result = new StreamResult( outputXMLFile );

          transformer.transform( xmlSource, result );

        }
      }
    
    }
    catch ( Exception exc )
    {
      exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outputXMLFile;
  
  }

  private static StringBuilder getXML( InputStream in )
  {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in ) );
    String line;
    try
    {
      while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
      {
        out.append( line );
      }
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out;
  }

}
```

Could anyone please point me towards the right approach to fix this? Also, if not this then how can we correctly use Enumeration to extract SevenZ files in String?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a complete example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @tgdavies I have updated the question with the code, my issue looks like is somethig with taking entry as getInputStream ?

Comment: @tgdavies I have edited the code with better information, I hope it helps now